# Setting Alarm for Particular Timings with Respect to Start Date and End Date of EKEvent in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I am having an Calendar Event with start date as 2-Feb-2015,end date as 6-Feb-2015  and I am having two timings 8:00AM and 9:00PM which are chosen from UIDatePicker with UIDatePickerModeTime.

As per Start Date of Event the alarm/reminder to be fired at above two timings. User can change the time as per his wish using DatePicker.

If I add them to event then it is showing with start date only as

Alerts,

Mon, Feb 2, 8:00AM

Mon, Feb 2, 9:00PM

But when I go to Calendar and select Feb3 then also alerts is showing as

Alerts,

Mon, Feb 2, 8:00AM

Mon, Feb 2, 9:00PM

//Instead of below

Alerts,

Mon, Feb 3, 8:00AM

Mon, Feb 3, 9:00PM

Does it fire at 8AM and 9PM from Feb 2 to Feb 6? Else what I need to modify to fire as per my requirement..

Here is the code I tried so far..

```
event.alarms = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:pickerFirstAlarm.date],[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:pickerSecondAlarm.date], nil];
```

Is any way of handling like above using alarmWithRelativeOffset of EKAlarm..

I need to fire an Reminder/Alarm at different alarm timings with respect to start and end date...

Any Ideas/Suggestions will be appreciated..

Thanks In Advance..!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)addEventToCalendar
 {

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc]init];
    if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])            {
// iOS 6 and later
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted,   NSError *error) {
    if (granted){

    //for IOS > 6.0
   EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
   [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

  //no need to fill all fill which one u want to set
   event.title =@"eventTitle";
   event.location = @"eventLocation";
   event.notes = @eventNote";
   event.startDate =  eventStartDate; //set date
   event.endDate = eventEndTime;
   event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

  //for alert set the aleram and notify the user rest is taken care by calendar for u 

   switch (evetReminder) {   //set alaram for 5mins, 15mins ,20mins etc
    case 0:
        self.selectedAlertSetting = @"None";
        break;

    case 1:
    {
        EKAlarm *alaram = [[EKAlarm alloc]init];
        [alaram setAbsoluteDate:eventStartDate];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        [alaram release];
        break;
    }


    case 2:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -5 *60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -15 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -30 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -1 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -2 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }

    case 7:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -1 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -2 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}

  //finally add it to calendar
  NSError *err = nil;
  BOOL complete = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
  if(err)
 {
    NSLog(@"error in storing event");
 }
 else
    NSLog(@"successfully added");

 if(complete)
 {
     NSLog(@"successfully added");
 }
 else
 {
    NSLog(@"error in storing event");
 }

 [eventStore release];

 }

 }];

 }
  else
 {
    //for IOS < 6.0
   // perform  same action hear
   EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
   [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

  //no need to fill all fill which one u want to set
   event.title =@"eventTitle";
   event.location = @"eventLocation";
   event.notes = @eventNote";
   event.startDate =  eventStartDate; //set date
   event.endDate = eventEndTime;
   event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

  //for alert set the aleram and notify the user rest is taken care by calendar for u 

   switch (evetReminder) {   //set alaram for 5mins, 15mins ,20mins etc
    case 0:
        self.selectedAlertSetting = @"None";
        break;

    case 1:
    {
        EKAlarm *alaram = [[EKAlarm alloc]init];
        [alaram setAbsoluteDate:eventStartDate];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        [alaram release];
        break;
    }


    case 2:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -5 *60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -15 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -30 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -1 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -2 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }

    case 7:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -1 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        NSTimeInterval aInterval = -2 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
        [event addAlarm:alaram];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
  }

  //finally add it to calendar
  NSError *err = nil;
  BOOL complete = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
  if(err)
 {
    NSLog(@"error in storing event");
 }
 else
    NSLog(@"successfully added");

 if(complete)
 {
     NSLog(@"successfully added");
 }
 else
 {
    NSLog(@"error in storing event");
 }



[eventStore release];
  }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering...I know how to add event..But I need to add alarm from StartDate to EndDate with mentioned timings..i.e; 8AM and 8PM....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can add multiple alarm for one event. As per you know how to add event I will give code only for alarm here. I have swift code:

```
if startingDate.isLaterThan(NSDate()) {

    let alarm1 = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: startingDate)
    let alarm2 = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: endingDate)

    event.alarms = [alarm1,alarm2]

} else if endingDate.isLaterThan(NSDate()) {
     event.addAlarm(EKAlarm(absoluteDate: endingDate))
}
```

Here in this code I need to two alarm at start and at end so I have added two alarm, but you can add multiple at your needed time. And compared time greater than current time. For date and time manipulations I have used date tools. https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools. You can easily convert it to Objective C in your need.